# Closed form for estimated sum with different asymptotic bounds?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, asymptotics, discrete-calculus

I found asymptotic lower and upper bounds for a summation as follows:

$$ 1 - O\left(\frac{\log_2^2 n}{n}\right) \le \sum_{k=1}^n f(k) \le 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$

If you want to write it in a closed form, how would you write it? Can you say:
$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd write $1+o(1)$, or "$1+O(1/n^c)$ for all $c>1$", or $1+\tilde{O}(1/n)$, or $1+O(\log^2 n/n)$; depending on the level of precision needed.

Comment: In the statement of the question, I should've written $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$. 
 @ClementC. , probably you mean $1+O(1/n^c)$, for all $0<c<1$, since for such choice of $c$, we have $\frac{\log^2 n / n}{1/n^c} \rightarrow 0$ as $n$ approaches infinity. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the typo. As a matter of fact, to emcompass both bounds at once the simplest (albeit not most elegant) way would be to write $\lvert \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k) - 1\rvert = O\left(\frac{\log^2 n}{n}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some ambiguity in your formulation.

If, for appropriate $f$, as $N \rightarrow +\infty$, we have
$$ \sum_{n=n_0}^{N} f(n) = 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right) \tag1$$
**then**
$$ \sum_{n=n_0}^{N} f(n) = 1 + O\left(\frac{\log_2^2 N}{N}\right) \tag2$$
that's what can be said in general.

The converse implication: $(1) \Leftarrow (2)$ is false.

A counter-example:
We have $$
\frac{\log_2 N}{N}=O\left(\frac{\log_2^2 N}{N}\right)
$$ but
$$
\log_2 N = \frac{\frac{\log_2 N}{N}}{\frac{1}{N}} \longrightarrow +\infty
$$ and
$$
\frac{\log_2 N}{N}\neq O \left(\frac{1}{N}\right)
$$ as $N \rightarrow +\infty$.